# Soundcard Tascam us-122 not working on 18.04

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard

I am trying to have my sound card working on Ubuntu Studio updated to 18.04 .
The procedures I found on the internet doesn't seem to work anymore on recent ubuntu systems.

Medibuntu repository doesn't exist anymore.
The file alsa-firmware-1.0.19.tar.bz2wget doesn't exist anymore.

Does someone successfully installed this soundcard.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Currently the most updated documentation is [Tascam US-122](https://alsa.opensrc.org/Tascam_US-122) on Opensrc Org. It contains valid URL for alsa-firmware v.1.0.29. Latest version (currently v.1.2.1) can be downloaded from [Alsa Project](ftp://ftp.alsa-project.org/pub/firmware/) or [GitHub](https://github.com/alsa-project/alsa-firmware/releases).

On Ubuntu 19.10, all mentioned installation steps was done.

When USB plug is disconnected and is immediately connected, PulseAudio inputs appear, but no outputs.

Both `arecord -l` and `aplay -l` give:

```
card 2: USX2Y [TASCAM US-X2Y], device 0: US-X2Y Audio [US-X2Y Audio #0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

When firmware is loaded, is not possible to stand-by computer, operating system is frozen.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue: I cannot shutdown and the OS is frozen!